# FreeTDS returns SQL Decimal as float

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, pyodbc, freetds

With OS Windows, Python 3.4, pyodbc with SQL Server driver, it converts (and it's correct) SQL Decimal(18,6) to python decimal.Decimal.

With Linux, Python 3.4, pyodbc and FreeTDS 0.91-6 driver, same column is converted to python float (and all problems related to float rounding).

Is there a way to force FreeTDS to convert SQL Numeric/Decimal to python's decimal.Decimal as it should be by default ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a workaround by specifying TDS_Version=8.0 in ODBC connection string as it is stated here :
[FreeTDS bug back from 2010](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/web2py/0PAGbXL38Gs/WV6tECLylscJ)

Comment: Note that TDS version 8.0 is simply an alias for version 7.1, and specifying 8.0 "should be avoided due to future compatibility concerns" (details [here](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm)).